# Send SMS of more than 160 characters in Python using Twilio

Tags: twilio

The [Twilio FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters) says we can send more-than-160-character messages using message resource URI. But I'm new to this and am writing an app in Django, so if anyone could give me a head start (a small example) on how to use Message Resource URI to send >160 characcter SMS, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Messages endpoint, you should just be able to send a message with more than 160 characters. It's possible that third party libraries like django-twilio do not support the new endpoint, in which case I'd recommend using the twilio-python library from inside your Django app.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. I also got a snippet of Python code that does allow sending SMS of >160 chars. It goes like `client.messages.create(body=msg_content, to=to_num, from_=from_num)` as opposed to the older version `client.sms.messages.create(body=msg_content, to=to_num, from_=from_num)`, which doesn't allow that

Comment: Just to note, carrier limitations can also cause issues.